# Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, android-listview

I need help!, please. When I delete the first item in the list, after deleting all, it closes the application.

I detail what it says on the console:

The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes.

this is the code last `onCreate()` :

```
private void listarDatos(){
        databaseReference.child("example").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                listDatos.clear();
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

                    for(DataSnapshot objSnapyshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        Datos p = objSnapyshot.getValue(Datos.class);
                        listDatos.add(p);
                        arrayAdapterDatos = new ArrayAdapter<Datos>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listDatos);
                        listV_personas.setAdapter(arrayAdapterDatos);
                    }

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void iniciarFirebase(){
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference= firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.icon_delete) {
            Datos ip = new Datos();
            ip.setUid(DatosSelected.getUid());
            databaseReference.child("example").child(ip.getUid()).removeValue();
            LimpiarCajas();
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void LimpiarCajas() {
        nombreP.setText("");
        distritoP.setText("");
        direccionP.setText("");
        referenciaP.setText("");
        telefonoP.setText("");
        productoP.setText("");
        pagoP.setText("");
    }

//....and class for the 'getter and setter'

public class Datos {

    private String Uid;
    private String Anombre;
    private String Bdistrito;
    private String Cdireccion;
    private String Dreferencia;
    private String Etelefono;

    public Datos(){

    }

    public String getUid() {
        return Uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        Uid = uid;
    }

    public String getAnombre() {
        return Anombre;
    }

    public void setAnombre(String anombre) {
        Anombre = anombre;
    }

    public String getBdistrito() {
        return Bdistrito;
    }

    public void setBdistrito(String bdistrito) {
        Bdistrito = bdistrito;
    }

    public String getCdireccion() {
        return Cdireccion;
    }

    public void setCdireccion(String cdireccion) {
        Cdireccion = cdireccion;
    }

    public String getDreferencia() {
        return Dreferencia;
    }

    public void setDreferencia(String dreferencia) {
        Dreferencia = dreferencia;
    }

    public String getEtelefono() {
        return Etelefono;
    }

    public void setEtelefono(String etelefono) {
        Etelefono = etelefono;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return Anombre;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

You can try call `arrayAdapterDatos.notifyDataSetChanged();` rigth after calling `LimpiarCajas();` method

If that doesn't work try call `arrayAdapterDatos.notifyDataSetChanged();` right after `listV_personas.setAdapter(arrayAdapterDatos);`